# IntelliJ Golang plugin not able to import default packages

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

I just downloaded the latest plugin for Go support in IntelliJ. I'm not able to use intellisense for Go programming because IntelliJ is not able to import packages like fmt and float64.

However, if I run the program from within IntelliJ, it works just fine!

**GOROOT** is `usr/local/go`
Project **GOPATH** is `/Users/myname/go` where the go file is.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Not sure how IntelliJ for Go works, but in a non-IDE Go environment you would have only one `GOPATH` and all your projects would live under `GOPATH/src/`, e.g. `GOPATH/src/MyGoProject`, in such an environment having project specific GOPATHs is gonna cause trouble. But if that's how it's done in IntelliJ then please, do ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Go | GOROOT and make sure your GOROOT is selected there. Then to the same place, but in GOPATH, make sure that's also set correctly.

Also, make sure that you follow the Go Workspace requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading my IntelliJ IDEA to the latest.